# How to add JTextField in time running in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

In order to develop a edit text in java for study. I'm with a problem: My program once opened by the user, if the user to click in button "Search", then the `ActionListener` will  add a field in Jpanel.

For example: I have a class JToolBar that sets up jtoolbar menu that extends JPanel. Then, I add it in `JFrame`. Within that JToolbar there's a  button "Search", if the user to click at this button, a `JTextField` will appears side this menu instantly.

I try to create a class private within that `JToolBar` class. So, I just add the JTextField to  `JPanel` contains the `JToolbar`. However, is not working. There's no error. Simply not appears the `JTextField`. What I do to solve that problem ?

Comment: What exactly not working? post some code and some errors if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a component to a visible GUI the general code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();  // sometimes needed
```

You need the revalidate() to tell the layout manager that a component has been added.

Comment: That's nice! It worked! Just one command, resolved the problem. Thank you very much !